# SQL Brainstorming

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Seeking help with the joins, with building the text fields.

Table 1 called as a driver table which tell which basepart attribute has to compare with which likepart attributes.

ALL Action and comparison will be performed on table 2.

if any value present with basepart and missing with like part should be in output with message column for eg:- (Make 15 is not available with basepart  MCN442941). similarly for Basepart.

if there is  difference in a two columns of single rows then both should be in output.

Sample table with Expected output given below.

```
CREATE TABLE DRIVER 
(
  BasePart varchar(50),
  likepart varchar (50)
)

insert into DRIVER select 'MCNW10',   'MCNW10__'  
insert into DRIVER select 'MCNW20',   'MCNW20__'
insert into DRIVER select 'MCN442941','MCN4_2941'

CREATE TABLE PARTS
(
  part varchar(50), 
  Make varchar(50), 
  Model varchar(50),
  Year varchar(50),
  remarks varchar(50),
  remarks2 varchar(50),
  remarks3 varchar(50)
)

insert into Parts select 'MCNW10','40','353','2001','FLOORMAT','CLASS','FRONT'
insert into Parts select 'MCNW10','40','353','2001','FLOORMAT','CLASS','FRONT'
insert into Parts select 'MCNW20','90','555','2015','DOORMAT','CLASS','REAR'
insert into Parts select 'MCNW20','90','555','2015','DOORMAT','CLASS','REAR'
insert into Parts select 'MCNW10','555','111','1975','CATCH ME','CLASS','FRONT'
insert into Parts select 'MCNW10GR','40','353','2001','FLOORMAT','CLASS','FRONT'
insert into Parts select 'MCNW10TN','40','8888','2001','FLOORMAT','CLASS','FRONTREAR'
INSERT INTO Parts SELECT 'MCN442941','65','548','2007','SLE, CREW ','front','V335'
INSERT INTO Parts SELECT 'MCN442941','65','548','2007','SLE, CREW ','front','V335'
INSERT INTO Parts SELECT 'MCN442941','A65','B548','2025','SLE, CREW ','front','V335'
INSERT INTO Parts SELECT 'MCN452941','65','548','2007','SLE, CREW ','front','V335'
INSERT INTO Parts SELECT 'MCN452941','65','548','2007','SLE, CREW ',  ''   ,'V335'
INSERT INTO Parts SELECT 'MCN482941','15','222','2016','SLE, CREW ','front','V335'
INSERT INTO Parts SELECT 'MCN442941','A65','B548','2025','SLE, CREW ','front','V335'
```

and expected output with alias message column. Message column is required uttermost.

```
--expected  output
/*
 part      ,Make    ,Model ,Year  ,remarks         remarks2      remarks3    BasePart    likepart      (comment)
'MCNW10TN','40',   '8888','2001','FLOORMAT',      'CLASS',     'FRONTREAR', MCNW10,    MCNW10TN,    8888 model is not available with base part MCNW10
'MCNW10TN','40',   '8888','2001','FLOORMAT',      'CLASS',     'FRONTREAR', MCNW10,    MCNW10TN,    FRONTREAR Remarks3 is not available with base part MCNW10
'MCNW10'  ,'555'   ,'111','1975','CATCH ME'       ,'CLASS'     ,'FRONT' ,   MCNW10,    MCNW10GR,    Catch me is not available with like part MCNW10GR
'MCNW10'  ,'555'   ,'111','1975','CATCH ME'       ,'CLASS'     ,'FRONT' ,   MCNW10,    MCNW10TN,    Catch me is not available with like part MCNW10TN
'MCN452941','65',   '548','2007','SLE, CREW ',      '',         'V335'  ,  MCN442941,  MCN452941,  '' remarks2 is not available with base part MCN442941
'MCN482941','15',   '222','2016','SLE, CREW ',     'front',     'V335', MCN442941,     MCN452941,   Make 15 is not available with basepart  MCN442941
'MCN482941','15',   '222','2016','SLE, CREW ',     'front',     'V335', MCN442941,     MCN452941,   Model 222 is not available with basepart  MCN442941
'MCN482941','15',   '222','2016','SLE, CREW ',     'front',     'V335', MCN442941,     MCN452941,   Year 2016 is not available with basepart  MCN442941
'MCN442941','A65',  'B548','2025','SLE, CREW ',    'front',     'V335', MCN442941,     MCN452941,   MAKE A65 is not present with like part MCN452941
'MCN442941','A65',  'B548','2025','SLE, CREW ',    'front',     'V335', MCN442941,     MCN452941,   Model B548 is not present with like part MCN452941
'MCN442941','A65',  'B548','2025','SLE, CREW ',    'front',     'V335', MCN442941      MCN452941,   year 2025 is not present with like part MCN452941
'MCN442941','A65',  'B548','2025','SLE, CREW ',    'front',     'V335', MCN442941      MCN482941,   MAKE A65 is not present with like part MCN482941
'MCN442941','A65', 'B548','2025','SLE, CREW ',    'front',     'V335', MCN442941      MCN482941    Model B548 is not present with like part MCN482941
'MCN442941','A65',  'B548','2025','SLE, CREW ',    'front',     'V335', MCN442941      MCN482941,   year 2025 is not present with like part MCN482941
```

i have tried this code, but failed to form comment column

```
 SELECT   DISTINCT
     B.part AS BasePart ,
     L.part AS LikePart ,
     STUFF(IIF(B.make != L.make, ', make: ' + L.make, '') + IIF(B.model != L.model, ', model: ' + L.model, '')
           + IIF(B.[year] != L.[year], ', year: ' + L.[year], '') + IIF(B.remarks != L.remarks, ', remarks: ' + L.remarks, '')
           + IIF(B.remarks2 != L.remarks2, ', remarks2: ' + L.remarks2, '') + IIF(B.remarks3 != L.remarks3, ', remarks3: ' +
     L.remarks, ''), 1, 2, '') AS attrib_diff FROM    @Parts B
     INNER JOIN @Driver D ON D.BasePart = B.part
     INNER JOIN @Parts L ON L.part LIKE D.likepart WHERE   B.part != L.part;
```

Comment: It's not very clear how are you expecting to get that result with this input.

Comment: Try breaking this problem down into smaller parts. It's not clear whether you're asking for help with the joins, with building the text fields, or what - there are just too many questions in here.

Comment: @Brent: Hi Brent. i am looking help with  the joins, with building the text fields. Edited the question in smaller parts. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BrentOzar: my biggest challenge is to frame the alias message column. Thanks.......

Comment: where is the message column in expected output?

Comment: i am able to point out the difference, but not able to framed message column (Comment), shall i share the query.

Comment: i called message column as comment

Comment: include your query what you tried?

Answer (score 0):

There is no IIF function in SQL Server. You should use a CASE expression instead:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT
     B.part AS BasePart ,
     L.part AS LikePart ,
     STUFF(
        CASE WHEN B.make != L.make THEN ', make: ' + L.make ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN B.model != L.model THEN ', model: ' + L.model ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN B.[year] != L.[year] THEN ', year: ' + L.[year] ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN B.remarks != L.remarks THEN ', remarks: ' + L.remarks ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN B.remarks2 != L.remarks2 THEN ', remarks2: ' + L.remarks2 ELSE '' END
        + CASE WHEN B.remarks3 != L.remarks3 THEN ', remarks3: ' + L.remarks3 ELSE '' END
    , 1, 2, '') AS attrib_diff 
FROM    Parts B
INNER JOIN Driver D ON D.BasePart = B.part
INNER JOIN Parts L ON L.part LIKE D.likepart WHERE   B.part != L.part;
```

However, your table structure seems very odd. Why do you have duplicates in the parts table?

**Later edit (23 June):** Regarding your comment, I'm not sure I understood it correctly, but try something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  DISTINCT
         B.part AS BasePart ,
         L.part AS LikePart ,
         X.Attribute,
         CASE x.Attribute
            WHEN 'make' THEN B.Make
            WHEN 'model' THEN B.Model
            WHEN 'year' THEN B.Year
            WHEN 'remarks' THEN B.remarks
            WHEN 'remarks2' THEN B.remarks2
            WHEN 'remarks3' THEN B.remarks3
        END AS BaseAttribute,
        CASE x.Attribute
            WHEN 'make' THEN L.Make
            WHEN 'model' THEN L.Model
            WHEN 'year' THEN L.Year
            WHEN 'remarks' THEN L.remarks
            WHEN 'remarks2' THEN L.remarks2
            WHEN 'remarks3' THEN L.remarks3
        END AS LikeAttribute
    FROM    Parts B
    INNER JOIN Driver D ON D.BasePart = B.part
    INNER JOIN Parts L ON L.part LIKE D.likepart 
    CROSS JOIN (
        SELECT 'make' AS Attribute
        UNION ALL SELECT 'model' AS Attribute
        UNION ALL SELECT 'year' AS Attribute
        UNION ALL SELECT 'remarks' AS Attribute
        UNION ALL SELECT 'remarks2' AS Attribute
        UNION ALL SELECT 'remarks3' AS Attribute
    ) X
    WHERE   B.part != L.part
) Q WHERE BaseAttribute<>LikeAttribute
```

**Later edit (1 July):** Considering your latest comment, you could use this query:

```
SELECT *, 
    CASE 
        WHEN Y.BaseAttribute IS NULL AND Y.LikeAttribute IS NOT NULL
        THEN Attribute+' '+LikeAttribute+' is not available with basepart '+BasePart+' but it is present with like part'
        WHEN Y.BaseAttribute IS NOT NULL AND Y.LikeAttribute IS NULL
        THEN Attribute+' '+BaseAttribute+' is not available with like part '+likepart+' but it is present with base part'
    END AS Message
FROM dbo.DRIVER D
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 'make' AS Attribute
    UNION ALL SELECT 'model' AS Attribute
    UNION ALL SELECT 'year' AS Attribute
    UNION ALL SELECT 'remarks' AS Attribute
    UNION ALL SELECT 'remarks2' AS Attribute
    UNION ALL SELECT 'remarks3' AS Attribute
) X
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT CASE X.Attribute
                WHEN 'make' THEN B.Make
                WHEN 'model' THEN B.Model
                WHEN 'year' THEN B.Year
                WHEN 'remarks' THEN B.remarks
                WHEN 'remarks2' THEN B.remarks2
                WHEN 'remarks3' THEN B.remarks3
            END AS BaseAttribute
        FROM dbo.PARTS B
        WHERE B.part=D.BasePart
    ) Y1
    FULL OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT CASE X.Attribute
                WHEN 'make' THEN L.Make
                WHEN 'model' THEN L.Model
                WHEN 'year' THEN L.Year
                WHEN 'remarks' THEN L.remarks
                WHEN 'remarks2' THEN L.remarks2
                WHEN 'remarks3' THEN L.remarks3
            END AS LikeAttribute
        FROM dbo.PARTS L
        WHERE L.part LIKE D.likepart
    ) Y2 ON Y1.BaseAttribute=Y2.LikeAttribute
) Y 
WHERE Y.BaseAttribute IS NULL AND Y.LikeAttribute IS NOT NULL 
    OR Y.BaseAttribute IS NOT NULL AND Y.LikeAttribute IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank You Very much Razvan. will it be possible to display result in a seperate row for each value currently shown with comma seperated.something like this.   8888 model is not available with base part MCNW10 or FRONTREAR Remarks3 is not available with base part MCNW10. i want to see whether changes occur in base part or like part. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Razvan,. unfortunately i am not looking this. what i am looking is  for eg:- if any value present with basepart and missing with like part should be in output with message column for eg:- (Make 15 is not available with basepart MCN442941 but it is present with like part). or present with likepart and not with base. for eg:- MAKE A65 is not present with like part MCN452941 but it is present with base part. please help.